# Finding runtime of a recurrence relation with a fractional power

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, master-theorem

Consider the following algorithm and find the tightest Big-$O$:

[image]

Assume $\texttt{multiplyKS}$($A,B$) is $O(n^{1.58})$ and $\texttt{Add}($A,B$)$ is $O(n)$.

If my runtime is $T(n)$, I have:

1. Lines 1 through 2 is $T(0)=d$, where $d$ is some constant
2. Line 3 is $T(n/2)$
3. Line 4 is $cn^{1.58}$, where $c$ is some constant
4. I ignore lines 5 through 6 because they are negligible, long term
5. Lines 7 through 8 is $kn$, where $k$ is some constant

Then I have:

$T(n)=T(n/2)+cn^{1.58}+kn$

After some research, I found that I can simplify (?) my runtime, by def. of Big-$O$, to:

$T(n)=T(n/2)+cn^{1.58}$

Have I done this correctly? If so, does this imply that I can use the Master Theorem to find Big-$O$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "runtime of a recurrence". I think what you mean is "solution of the recurrence". The recurrence measures the runtime of an *algorithm*.

Comment: You are claiming that $cn^{1.58} + kn = cn^{1.58}$, but this is plainly false. What is correct is that $cn^{1.58} + kn = O(n^{1.58})$.